# java android - Socket connects but do not send or receive data

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm stuck up with this issue I can't receive even PIN msg from the server, and sending data to the server does not work for me. However, the whenever I check the socket.isConnected() it returns true. How can I fix this issue? Here's my code for the client side.

```
public class Socks {
private Socket sockets;
private OutputStream socketOutput;
private BufferedReader socketInput;

private String ip;
private int port;
private SocksCallback listener=null;

public Socks(String ip, int port){
    this.ip=ip;
    this.port=port;
    Log.d("GEGE","GEGEGEGE");
    connect();
}

public void connect(){
    Log.i("SOCKET","Trying to connect...");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sockets = new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
            try {
                sockets.connect(socketAddress);
                if(sockets.isConnected()){
                    Log.i("SOCKET","Connected");
                }
                socketOutput = sockets.getOutputStream();
                socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockets.getInputStream()));

                new ReceiveThread().start();

                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onConnect(sockets);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(listener!=null)

                    listener.onConnectError(sockets, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void disconnect(){
    try {
        sockets.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(listener!=null)
        // Log.i("SEND_ON_ERROR",e.getMessage());

            listener.onDisconnect(sockets, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void send(String message){
    try {
        Log.i("SEND_ON_SOCKET",message);
        socketOutput.write(message.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(listener!=null)

            listener.onDisconnect(sockets, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private class ReceiveThread extends Thread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        String message;
        try {
            Log.i("THREAD","WIW");
            while((message = socketInput.readLine()) != null) {   // each line must end with a \n to be received
                Log.d("MSG",message);
                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onMessage(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(listener!=null)
                listener.onDisconnect(sockets, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void setClientCallback(ClientCallback listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

public void removeClientCallback(){
    this.listener=null;
}

public interface SocksCallback {
    void onMessage(String message);
    void onConnect(Socket sockets);
    void onDisconnect(Socket sockets, String message);
    void onConnectError(Socket sockets, String message);
}
```

}

Anyone who got this issue and solved it? Even your ideas will be great help

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Add a line terminator to the message to send. You need to remove your listener when you reach end of stream. NB `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you're testing it. Don't write pointless code.

Comment: I found this code on one of the tutorials. Do you have any reliable tutorials for that?

Comment: Which tutorial?

Comment: The only tutorial you should use is the Oracle Java Tutorial, in this case the Custom Networking section, but note that even this tutorial isn't infallible. Everything else out there is suspect, and that includes some well-known books.

Comment: @StephenC at this site: https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/27/node-js-android-tcpip/

Comment: Do Socket can listen to any kind of server?

Comment: `Socket` can't 'listen' to *any* kind of server, but `ServerSocket` can listen for any TCP clients. Your tutorial contains most of the errors you've perpetrated here, but you've added some of your own.

Comment: I noticed that most of the threads I read most of them requiring the data from the server with this /n at the end. In order for them to receive the data.

Comment: That's what I told you an hour ago. If you use `readLine()` you must have line-terminated messages. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @MadDev - The thing is, if you simply treat tutorial sites as places to copy code from, you tend to miss the explanations (if they exist) ... and you don't actually learn.  And yes, you need to use a decent tutorial site.  I second user207421's recommendation of using (only) the Oracle site for things related to the Java standard libraries.  Finally ... take the time to read them, and try to understand them.

Comment: The problems with material on a lot of tutorial sites is that it is often written by people who are not experts and not good teachers.  And the sites themselves often care more about income from their advertisers than the quality of their material.  (If they are showing you adverts, you are the product not the customer!)

Comment: Your listener is probably null. Try checking your code again and see if it was set on other files on your code.

Comment: An `IOException` from `readLine()` is not a disconnect, it is a connection error.